# Dialogflow request not receiving all data

Tags: json, swift, curl, dialogflow-es

I made a Dialogflow agent, and it works perfectly on the web version, but the iOS client does not receive the fulfillment field when a query matches an entity.

Here is one example of the web json response:

```
{
  "responseId": "da8588ce-c447-412f-a71e-e98b8552e1a1",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "metlife",
    "action": "qualify.wantToMakeCoPayCardQuestion",
    "parameters": {
      "prov": "Metlife"
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Yes you Metlife qualifies<Would you like to generate a co-pay card?",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Yes you Metlife qualifies<Would you like to generate a co-pay card?"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/h-ac087/agent/sessions/061f4b0d-7622-54a4-b43d-57f9c0421807/contexts/provider",
        "lifespanCount": 5,
        "parameters": {
          "prov.original": "metlife",
          "prov": "Metlife"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/h-ac087/agent/sessions/061f4b0d-7622-54a4-b43d-57f9c0421807/contexts/canyoucheckifmyinsurancecovershumira-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "prov.original": "metlife",
          "prov": "Metlife"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/h-ac087/agent/sessions/061f4b0d-7622-54a4-b43d-57f9c0421807/contexts/canyoucheckifmyinsurancecovers-custom-followup",
        "lifespanCount": 2,
        "parameters": {
          "prov.original": "metlife",
          "prov": "Metlife"
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
  "name": "projects/h-ac087/agent/intents/77983090-84b2-4c19-86c1-790b1dd9eaff",
  "displayName": "What is the name of your insurance provider?"
},
"intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
"diagnosticInfo": {},
"languageCode": "en"
  }
}
```

However the iOS client only receives this:
[client json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5hU6.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!